# Unable to get array data from form elements within a loop in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I have this form:

```
<?php echo flash_message_success('status_msg'); ?>

<?php echo form_open('students/mark_attendance/'.$session.'/'.$term.'/'.$class_id); ?>  

    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_all" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="All Present" data-off="All Absent" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" />

    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($students as $s) {

        $student_id = $s->id; ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="student_id[]" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>" />

        <input class="bulk_select_present" type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Present" />Present

        <input class="bulk_select_absent" type="radio" name="status[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="Absent" />Absent

        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="<?php echo set_value('date'); ?>" required />

        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Mark Attendance</button>

<?php echo form_close() //mark_attendance ?>
```

And this is the function which are process my form:

```
public function attendance($session, $term, $slug) {
        $class_details = $this->common_model->get_class_details_by_slug(school_id, $slug);
        $page_title = 'Attendance: ' . $class_details->class;
        $this->admin_header($page_title, $page_title);  
        $data['session'] = $session;
        $data['term'] = $term;
        $data['class_id'] = $class_details->id;
        $data['slug'] = $slug;
        $data['students'] = $this->common_model->get_students_list_by_class($class_details->id);
        $this->load->view('admin/students/attendance', $data);
        $this->admin_footer();
    }


public function mark_attendance($session, $term, $class_id) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('student_id[]', 'Student ID', 'trim');

        $student_id = $this->input->post('student_id', TRUE);
        $status = $this->input->post('status', TRUE);
        $date = $this->input->post('date', TRUE);

        $slug = $this->common_model->get_class_details($class_id)->slug;

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($student_id); $i++) {
                $d_id = $student_id[$i];
                $d_status = $status[$i];

                //check if student was marked absent or absent
                if ($d_status == 'Present') {
                    $this->students_model->mark_student_present($session, $term, $class_id, $d_id);
                } else {
                    $this->students_model->mark_student_absent($session, $term, $class_id, $d_id);
                }
            }
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg', "Attendance marked successfully");
            redirect('students/attendance/'.$session.'/'.$term.'/'.$slug);

        } else {
            $this->attendance($session, $term, $slug); //reload page with validation errors
        }   
    }
```

Problem is, the data won't get submitted to the database (my model is working fine, i tested it). Some checks revealed that `$student_id` is not parsed as an array (I tried checking using is_array function and it returned false). I have no explanation for this behavior, I did a similar implementation in another module and it works fine. I have practically turned the function inside out but the problem persists. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Note: the above is a simplified version of the code, I removed what I felt isn't necessary for this question.

Comment: to surmise, your question is "why isn't student_id being parsed as an array?" ... upon viewing your code I see no reason for it to NOT be an array. what does a var_dump give you for that var?

Answer (score 0):

you can't echo an array in php. The suggested way is that you should convert the array into json object then store the json object as string in hidden field then when you submit the form should decode the json object then will get an array.

Comment: While your answer is helpful it could do with a code example to make it even more helpful!